# Getting the type of expression result in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

If I have an expression producing a result, say, new ClassA(), or "somestring", or whatever, and I have a corresponding ExpressionSyntax object, how do I get the INamedTypeSymbol object corresponding to the result of the expression?

Many tutorials mention the GetTypeInfo method, but I cannot find it in the latest Roslyn I got from NuGet. Is there something that replaces it?

Update: Somehow I had the 1.0 version of Roslyn. After updating it to 1.2, I found the GetTypeInfo method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to build the semantic model, like this:

```
var semanticModel = document.GetSemanticModel(cancellationToken);
var typeInfo = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(expression, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: This assumes you have a VS document. If you have just a `CompilationUnitSyntax`, getting `SemanticModel` is more complicated: you have first create a `SyntaxTree`, then `Compilation` and tghen you can get `SemanticModel`.

Comment: @svick Indeed, but I already know how to get the SemanticModel instance. Hope your comment helps others.